Custom crop need using a pre selected overlay on the image canvas
I have a code for dragging and selecting the image and cropping. However, the image is not moveable and there are no pointers in any corner. I want four pointers in the corners that can be clicked/touched and dragged to resize the image. Additionally, if clicked/touched in the center of the overlay, I should be able to move the pre-selected overlay with a fixed rectangle size. When I use object-fit: contain the drag function also does not work properly. I want my image to fit the container and be responsive, so there might be an issue in my CSS, but I'm not sure.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Image Cropper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=ZwFQZweTXHzP16h6nr2C00YR-EMUfaFMGvNAUzaTKE0yqJGtgyEzshGEut7aDqvNy5Kk95fBaTqLoJBgaVFQl-wn9hU17TF8ce3lySsVOd3wUJ_7026QrtsnTmlt_Hev-H0NvA-P-iDU9egcesQ0TqkAFxMpZgug6EKLzzEVXGTM-SNckV4J0o8ULg1I26KLRwFSf0mtvkqlEP3EIQR9K-R5wis3fGfQMJxOwyCGOM3KZWjy2AkQFVwRI401oii37_c2bXRI3h0rk7WijJw7UA"
    charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 90vh;
      /* Changed height to 95vh */
      background-color: #222;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    canvas {
      object-fit: contain;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 90vh;
      /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
      cursor: crosshair;
      max-width: 100%;
      /* Added max-width to prevent stretching */
      max-height: 100vh;
      /* Added max-height to prevent stretching */
      display: block;
      background-color: #222;
    }
    
    .button-container {
      position: relative;
      /* Positioning relative to the parent */
      margin-top: 10px;
      /* top: 10px; */
      /* Position at the top */
      /* display: flex; */
      /* justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; */
      /* width: 100%; */
      /* Full width */
      /* gap: 10px; */
    }
    
    .left-buttons {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .right-buttons {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .bottom-buttons {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      /* margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 8px; */
      /* Added margin-bottom to reduce space from bottom */
    }
    
    select {
      margin: 0 10px;
      background-color: #444;
      color: #fff;
    }
    /* Modal styles */
    
    .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      /* Semi-transparent background */
    }
    
    .modal-content {
      background-color: #333;
      margin: 0 auto;
      /* Center modal horizontally */
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #888;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      color: #aaa;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .modal-content img {
      max-width: 100%;
      /* Added max-width to prevent stretching */
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .zoom-buttons {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      right: 10px;
    }
    
    .zoom-buttons button {
      margin-left: 5px;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: black;
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .zoom-buttons button:hover {
      background-color: #666;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="left-buttons">
      <!-- <button onclick="zoomIn()"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></button>
      <button onclick="zoomOut()"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></button> -->
      <!-- <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage(event)" /> -->
      <!-- <button onclick="downloadImage()"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></button> -->
      <img id="brookImage" src="Rope1.JPG" style="display: none;" onload="loadImage()">
      <select id="shapeSelect" onchange="selectShape()">
        <option value="rectangle" selected>Rectangle</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="right-buttons">
      <button onclick="cropImage()"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
      <button onclick="resetImage()"><i class="fas fa-x"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <!-- <canvas id="croppedCanvas"></canvas> -->
  <div class="bottom-buttons">
    <button onclick="rotateLeft()"><i class="fas fa-rotate-left"></i></button>
    <button onclick="rotateRight()"><i class="fas fa-rotate-right"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="zoom-buttons bottom-right">
    <button onclick="zoomIn()"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut()"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></button>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <img id="croppedImagePreview" src="" alt="Cropped Image" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let imageObj = null;
    let startX, startY, endX, endY;
    let isDragging = false;
    let selectedShape = "rectangle";
    let shapes = [];
    let croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let croppedCtx = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");
    let scale = 1; // Initial scale
    let overlayX = 0;
    let overlayY = 0;
    let overlayWidth = 200;
    let overlayHeight = 200;
    let isResizing = false;
    let isDraggingOverlay = false;
    let resizeHandleSize = 10; // Size of the resize handle


    // function loadImage(event) {
    //   let file = event.target.files[0];
    //   let reader = new FileReader();
    //   reader.onload = function (event) {
    //     imageObj = new Image();
    //     imageObj.onload = function () {
    //       canvas.width = imageObj.width;
    //       canvas.height = imageObj.height;
    //       ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    //     };
    //     imageObj.src = "event.target.result";
    //   };
    //   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    // }

    function loadImage() {
      let imageElement = document.getElementById("brookImage");
      imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = imageObj.width;
        canvas.height = imageObj.height;
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      // Set the source of the image object to the loaded image element
      imageObj.src = imageElement.src;
    }

    function selectShape() {
      selectedShape = document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value;
    }

    function drawSelectionBox() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

      // Draw the selection box
      ctx.setLineDash([0, 0]); // Set line dash for rectangle
      ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow"; // Change border color to yellow
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;

      // Draw the selection box based on the selected shape
      if (selectedShape === "circle") {
        let radiusX = Math.abs(endX - startX) / 2;
        let radiusY = Math.abs(endY - startY) / 2;
        let centerX = (startX + endX) / 2; // Calculate center based on bounding box
        let centerY = (startY + endY) / 2; // Calculate center based on bounding box

        // Draw small circle pointers in all four corners
        const cornerSize = 6; // Size of the corner circles
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(startX, startY, cornerSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(startX, endY, cornerSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(endX, startY, cornerSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.ellipse(centerX, centerY, radiusX, radiusY, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
      } else if (selectedShape === "rectangle") {
        // Draw small circle pointers in all four corners
        const cornerSize = 6; // Size of the corner circles
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(startX, startY, cornerSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(startX, endY, cornerSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(endX, startY, cornerSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(endX, endY, cornerSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeRect(startX, startY, endX - startX, endY - startY);
      }

      // Draw overlay with opacity inside the crop area
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"; // Black with 50% opacity
      ctx.fillRect(startX, startY, endX - startX, endY - startY);
    }

    function cropImage() {
      let shape = {
        type: selectedShape,
        startX: startX,
        startY: startY,
        endX: endX,
        endY: endY,
      };
      shapes.push(shape);

      // Calculate width and height of the cropped area
      let width = Math.abs(endX - startX);
      let height = Math.abs(endY - startY);

      // Calculate top-left coordinates for cropping
      let cropX = Math.min(startX, endX);
      let cropY = Math.min(startY, endY);

      let tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      let tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

      tempCanvas.width = width;
      tempCanvas.height = height;

      if (shape.type === "rectangle") {
        tempCtx.drawImage(
          imageObj,
          cropX,
          cropY,
          width,
          height,
          0,
          0,
          width,
          height
        );
      } else if (shape.type === "circle") {
        let rx = width / 2; // Radius along x-axis
        let ry = height / 2; // Radius along y-axis
        let cx = rx; // Center along x-axis
        let cy = ry; // Center along y-axis

        tempCtx.save(); // Save the current context state
        tempCtx.beginPath();
        tempCtx.translate(cx, cy); // Translate to the center of the ellipse
        tempCtx.scale(1, ry / rx); // Scale to make the circle an ellipse
        tempCtx.arc(0, 0, rx, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        tempCtx.closePath();
        tempCtx.restore(); // Restore the previous context state
        tempCtx.clip();

        tempCtx.drawImage(
          imageObj,
          cropX,
          cropY,
          width,
          height,
          0,
          0,
          width,
          height
        );
      }

      croppedCanvas.width = width;
      croppedCanvas.height = height;
      croppedCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      croppedCtx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);

      // Show the modal with cropped image
      document.getElementById("croppedImagePreview").src =
        croppedCanvas.toDataURL();
      document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";

      // Get cropped image base64 data in console
      console.log(croppedCanvas.toDataURL());
    }

    function resetImage() {
      shapes = [];
      croppedCtx.clearRect(0, 0, croppedCanvas.width, croppedCanvas.height);
    }

    function closeModal() {
      document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
    }

    let rotation = 0;

    function rotateLeft() {
      rotation -= Math.PI / 2;
      drawRotatedImage(rotation);
    }

    function rotateRight() {
      rotation += Math.PI / 2;
      drawRotatedImage(rotation);
    }

    function drawRotatedImage(rotation) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.rotate(rotation);
      ctx.drawImage(
        imageObj, -canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2,
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height
      );
      ctx.restore();
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
      startX = event.offsetX;
      startY = event.offsetY;
      isDragging = true;
    });


    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (isDragging && event.buttons === 1) { // Check if left mouse button is pressed
        let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        let scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width;
        let scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;
        endX = (event.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX;
        endY = (event.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY;
        drawSelectionBox();
      }
    });

    // Event listener for mouseup
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
      isDragging = false;
    });

    function downloadImage() {
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = "cropped_image.png";
      link.href = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();
      link.click();
    }

    function zoomIn() {
      scale += 0.1;
      drawZoomedImage();
    }

    function zoomOut() {
      scale -= 0.1;
      drawZoomedImage();
    }

    function drawZoomedImage() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.save();

      // Translate to the center of the image
      ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

      // Scale the context
      ctx.scale(scale, scale);

      // Draw the image
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj, -canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      ctx.restore();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



I tried to create a CSS preselected overlay, but it's not working. I am expecting to have a preselected overlay that can be resized and moved. Additionally, any image size should be centered, and the object-fit: contain property should work.
